# Adding an element to a specific text position without removing event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have something like:

```html
<div id="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span id="some-span"></span> 
</div>
```

How could I add a span to a specific position of the text above? I don't want the span with the id some-span to lose its event listeners.

Comment: Can you post output desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo')
const span = document.querySelector('#some-span')

span.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('working'))

const text = foo.childNodes[0]
foo.removeChild(text)
foo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', text.wholeText.replace(/dolor/, '<span class="green">dolor</span>'))
```

```css
#some-span {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span id="some-span"></span>
</div>
```